# Resource files problem in sharepoint 2013 online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have added **resource** files in my app for two languages: ***English*** and ***Spanish***. It was working perfectly. In my client app part I have added app title as follows:

`$Resources:myApp_Title` but suddenly when I change the language to English it don't display title etc in English it still shows me in Spanish.

Anyone know wht could be the reason ?